# Apollo Server has no socket connection

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, typegraphql

I have a GraphQL server running with Type-GraphQL + Apollo and so I want to use a subscription.
For the frontend I am using NextJS + Apollos client and I am getting following error:
`WebSocket connection to: 'ws://localhost:8080/graphql' failed:  SubscriptionClient.connect @ client.js?2ed1:427 eval @ client.js?2ed1:396`

My code in the frontend client looks like this:

```js
const wsLink = process.browser ? new WebSocketLink({ // if you instantiate in the server, the error will be thrown
    uri: `ws://localhost:8080/graphql`,
    options: {
      reconnect: true
    }
  }) : null;
  
  const httplink = new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
      credentials: "include"
  });
  
  const link = process.browser ? split( //only create the split in the browser
    ({ query }) => {
        const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
        return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && definition.operation === 'subscription';
      },
    wsLink,
    httplink,
  ) : httplink;

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    fetch,
    credentials: "include",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to [apollo-link-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-ws) which fixed it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).